# What's the meaning of Array[string[i] - 'a'] in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I used it in this context but I don't understand why it is put Array[string[i] - 'a']

could someone explain me? because i'm trying finalizar una practica

---

**Example**

```
public int StringsCounter(string A, string B){
          int count =0;
          int[] freq = new int[9];
          int long1 = A.Length;
          
          int[] freq2 = new int[50];
          int long2 = B.Length;
          
          if(long1 >=3 && long1 <= 9 && long2 >=3 && long2 <= 50){
                   
            for (int i =0; i<long1; i++){
              freq[A[i] - 'a'] +=1;
              Console.Write(A[i]+" "+freq[A[i] - 'a']);
              Console.WriteLine(" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            for (int i =0; i<long2; i++){
              freq2[B[i] - 'a'] +=1;
              Console.Write(B[i]+" "+freq2[B[i] - 'a']);
              Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            count = int.MaxValue;
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            for (int i=0; i<long2; i++){
              if(freq2[B[i] - 'a'] >1){
                Console.WriteLine(freq2[B[i] - 'a']+"/"+freq[B[i] - 'a']);
                count = Math.Min(count, freq2[B[i] - 'a']/freq[B[i] - 'a']);
                Console.WriteLine(count);
              }else{
                count = 0;
              }
            }
            //Console.Write(count);
            return count;
          }
          return count;
        }
```

Comment: so its basically removing character A from all of characters in your string as its put inside for loop.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but it explains the logic behind subtracting chars.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.